# PostreSQL Server to CSV files - Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, csv, ubuntu-14.04

So my colleague gave a server (the physical mashine) running a postgresql database. That database is massive (around 1TB of data). Now I have to get this database of that server and transform everything to CSV.

I could have done it with the SQL commands he gave me. But over the network/internet that would take ages with this mass of data. Now I am thinking if there is a way to get this data of the pgSQL database and export it to CSV on that computer?

The computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The biggest problem is, I can't even find the data on the disk. If I could find the actual database in form of files to copy, that might help. But can't find that stuff in the first place...

Any help or ideas is appreciated!

Comment: Use SSIS to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you dump the data first on the DB computer itself in a compressed format. Of course you will have to have enough disk space for dumping the data. The command I would use on the DB computer, where the database is, would be:

```
pg_dump db_name | gzip -9 > dump.tar.gz
```

`pg_dump` is a PostGres utility which dumps the database content and should be available under the postgres user on the DB computer. By piping it directly to `gzip -9` you compress with the best possible compression.

After this you can download the file and re-create the database on another Linux machine where Postgres in the same version is installed using:

```
tar -xzvf dump.tar.gz
psql target_db_name postgres_user_name < dump.sql > import.log 2>&1
```

This should also happen after you have created on the target machine the database "target_db_name".

You could also use Windows as the target machine, but there you will have to use some tool like 7-Zip to extract the content of `dump.tar.gz`.

Comment: That sounds good. A slight problem is now that I don't have the password for the postgres user. Have to ask my colleague tomorrow.

Comment: Okay it is running now. That will take ages though. :)
It is not clear to me, how I get CSV files out of that dump later.

Comment: Well, there are many ways. I use Talend Open Studio for that. This is an ETL tool which can speed up this type of jobs. https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration/data-integration-open-studio/